# Best way to modify UIView Outside UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller

I try to create a class **MyViewControllerDesign.swift**, that handle all design setting, like configuration, modification... and that can be called from everywhere.

[image]

What is **the best way** to modify an UIView, that was created in a MyUIViewController, from an function of MyViewControllerDesign ?

1 - Should *I pass context of MyUIViewController to hideMyView function* ?

```
func hideMyView(context: MyUIViewController){
   context.myView.hidden = true
}
```

2 - Or should I *pass the view to hideMyView function* ?

```
func hideMyView(myView: UIView){
   myView.hidden = true
}
```

... but I have to pass it from startTasks too...

```
func startTasks(myView: UIView){
   ...
   myViewControllerDesign.hideMyView(myView)
   ...
}
```

3 - Or should I *let hideMyView function on MyUIViewController* ?

**What is the best way ? Is there a design pattern to handle that case ?**

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense for the Design Controller to hold a reference to the view and/or subviews that it manages -- you can do it when you instantiate `MyViewControllerDesign` in your View Controller. Similarly, your `BackgroundTasks` object can keep a reference to the Design Controller and call relevant methods as needed.

That way, the View Controller is still at the center of the process and links the model layer to the view layer.